# Undefined object in react js

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: videos2 is not defined
```

In this app:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        videos2:[],
        selectedVideo:null
    }

    this.DMSearch()
}

    DMSearch(){
        fetch("https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=description,id,thumbnail_url,title,&limit=5&search=cars")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data=>this.setState({
            videos2:data.videos2, 
            selectedVideo:videos2[0]}))
        console.log(videos2)
    }
    render () {
        const {videos2}=this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar onSearchTermChange= {DMSearch}/>
                <VideoDetail video={this.state.selectedVideo}/> 
                <VideoList 
                onVideoSelect={selectedVideo=>this.setState({selectedVideo})}
                videos2={this.state.videos2}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Therefore Im wondering where should I define videos2 apart from where it is defined already. Anyone could point me out to the part of the component that might be causing the error?

EDIT: Actually it had to do with the way api json was shaped. 
This is the proper way to fetch the list from json:

```
this.setState({
               videos2: videos2.list, 
               selectedVideo: videos2[0]
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

In `DMSearch` function there is no `videos2` variable defined. You probably want:

```
.then(data => {
    this.setState({
       videos2: data.videos2, 
       selectedVideo: data.videos2[0]
    });
    console.log(data.videos2);
 });
```

or

```
.then(data => {
    const { videos2 } = data;
    this.setState({
       videos2,
       selectedVideo:videos2[0]
    });
    console.log(videos2);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In DMSearch, `videos2` is undefined.

```js
DMSearch() {
  fetch("https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=description,id,thumbnail_url,title,&limit=5&search=cars")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let videos2 = data.videos2; //define it here

      this.setState({
        videos2: videos2,
        selectedVideo: videos2[0] // <-- this line will throw error
      })
    })
  console.log(videos2) // <-- and this too
}
```