# Accessing nested json in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can successfully fetch json object from the api. However there seems to be a problem in updating the state.
After printing the object I get expected and desired result `console.log(videos2.list[0]);` gives 1st item from the list attribute of json object, you can check how the api looks under this link:
https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=description,id,thumbnail_url,title,&limit=5&search=cars

However when updating state with setState property selectedVideo: videos.list[0] is undefined.

The code for the component:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
    videos2:[],
    selectedVideo:null
}
this.DMSearch()
}

DMSearch(){
    fetch(`https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=description,id,thumbnail_url,title,&limit=5&search=cars`)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(videos2 => {
        console.log(videos2.list[0]);
        this.setState({
           videos2: videos2.list, 
           selectedVideo: videos2.list[0]
        });
        console.log(selectedVideo);
     });  
    }  
render () {
    const DMSearch = this.DMSearch()
    return (
        <div>
            <SearchBar onSearchTermChange= {DMSearch}/>
            <VideoDetail video={this.state.selectedVideo}/> 
            <VideoList 
            onVideoSelect={selectedVideo=>this.setState({selectedVideo})}
            videos2={this.state.videos2}/>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

And exact error is `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: selectedVideo is not defined`

`videos2:list[0]` produces correct results, but when assigned to `selectedVideo` it is `undefined`

As requested I am also including the code for vide_list which uses the objects form parent component which might be producing error here:

```
const VideoList = (props) => {

    const videoItems = props.videos.map((video)=>{
        return (
        <VideoListItem 
            onVideoSelect={props.onVideoSelect}
            key={video.etag} 
            video={video} />
        )
    })

    return (
        <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
            {videoItems}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

To be specific, this line

```
const videoItems = props.videos.map((video)=> {
```

causes the error when reading props. I believe this has something to do with `selectedVideo` being null...

Comment: I suggest that you start by reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: If you still need help, show us the code for `VideoList` and how it calls `this.props.onVideoSelect()`. Also you should clearly indicate which line of code causes the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined object in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002334/undefined-object-in-react-js)

Comment: Downvoting because this is the exact duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: it is not, i solved that one already by myself and updated the question with my answer, here there is different issue

Comment: I added code for VideoList and explained which line is causing error. I think it all comes down to `selectedVideo` being still null even after giving it value in setState.

Comment: NVM it was a typo error, can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue at this line

console.log(selectedVideo);

You printed out an undefined variable. It should be this.state.selectedVideo.

Comment: The thing is it seems to not update itself. When i change to this.state.selectedVideo it give "null"

Comment: It will be nulled there, because the setState is an async function. It has a bit delay. But console.log(videos2.list[0]); show the data you want ?

Comment: that one shows it but then when i send the selectedvideo as you can see in the code to the child component and it is read as undefined there

Comment: The issue could be in the VideoDetail component. Although, something in this snippet should be refactored. Can you post the details of VideoDetail here ?

Answer (score -1):

The error `selectedVideo is not defined` happens because `selectedVideo` is not a variable, it is a key on the javascript object passed to `this.setState` function.

```
//...
this.setState({
   videos2: videos2.list, 
   selectedVideo: videos2.list[0]
});
//...
```

You can mitigate the error by creating a variable:

```
DMSearch(){
fetch(`https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=description,id,thumbnail_url,title,&limit=5&search=cars`)
.then(result => result.json())
.then(videos2 => {
    console.log(videos2.list[0]);
    const selectedVideo = videos2.list[0]; // create variable
    this.setState({
       videos2: videos2.list, 
       selectedVideo: selectedVideo
    });
    console.log(selectedVideo);
 });  
}
```